# Как дождаться загрузки всех скриптов js?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть два js файла такого типа `<script defer="" src="/static/CACHE/js/070e65d4886b.js"></script>`, подключение которых идёт после `</footer>` и перед `</body>`.

Внутри этих файлов куча всего, включая `bootstrap.js` и `jquery.js`.

В теле сайта, на разных страницах, иногда встречаются инлайн обработчики, которые не удаётся, по ряду причин, ужать и засунуть в один из общих файлов.

Каким образом можно дождаться загрузки больших файлов, находящихся ниже в DOM, учитывая, что я не могу наверняка знать их название заранее?

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Изначально, было так:

```
<head>
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script3.js"></script>
</head>
```

затем, находящиеся внутри `<body></body>` инлайн скрипты окружались привычным многим `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

и на деве это не вызывало проблем, т.к. скорость загрузки страницы не играла особой роли.

Сейчас же `$(document).ready(function(){...})` не работает, по всем понятным причинам.

Я знаю как дождаться загрузки скрипта с известным названием, но не понимаю, как сделать универсально.

Если `$(document).ready(function(){...})` заменить на `window.onload = function()` то ошибок вроде `$ is undefined` не возникает, но на некоторые элементы с `id` листенер не успевает повесится, и скрипт не срабатывает.

Comment: не понимаю, у вас уже есть defer, он для этого и нужен. [пример](https://plnkr.co/edit/7VwnNmqOEgoUlSBwU08W?p=preview)

Comment: В блоках <section></section> , которые встречаются на разных страницах сайта, бывают инлайн скрипты, которые не могут дождаться загрузки, скажем, jqery, и из-за этого неработает ajax, или же magnificpopup, и не работает модальное окно.

Comment: тогда надо убрать defer, либо сделать мини синхронный скрипт, который поймает все обращения к незагруженым либам и вызовет их после загрузки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните содержимое инлайн-скриптов в некую функцию method, например. Ждите, пока jQuery будет объявлено и после этого вызывайте функцию method.

```
function defer(method) {
  if (window.jQuery)
      method();
  else
      setTimeout(function() { defer(method) }, 50);
}
```

Пример с анонимной функцией:

```
defer(function () {
    alert("jQuery is now loaded");
});
```

Comment: эммм.... лучше уж потом в конце сразу все вызвать чем постоянный setTimeout ....

Comment: в конце - чего? и какая проблема в таймауте? это распространенный способ ожидания, затрат по ресурсам - 0.

Comment: А что касательно других либ, загрузки которых так же желательно дождаться ?

Comment: Так если они у вас в одном файле, можно и не проверять. А если в другом, добавить в if  проверку на их существование, аналогично jQuery

Comment: function method() { ... }; работает так же , как window.onload = function(..), т.е. не происходит ругани по поводу $ is undefined, но и скрипты не работают.

Comment: Так быть не должно. Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik а у вас там не webpack случаем, и если просто убрать defer, то заработает ? (судя по всему  - нет), а значит вам действительно нужно проксировать вызовы из inline.

Comment: @KAGGDesign в конце загрузки например, 50мс ожидание в худшем случае, когда все загрузилось из кэша, только на запуск...
выполнять в domContentLoaded .

Comment: Ваше решение сработало. Большое спасибо! 
Нашёл точно такое же тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486309/how-to-make-script-execution-wait-until-jquery-is-loaded
Единственное, вы не указали, что нужно обернуть функцией defer, а не method.
Исправьте рекомендацию к применению, я засчитаю Ваш ответ.

Comment: Что чем обернуть? ваши инлайн-скрипты нужно обернуть функцией method. defer ждет и как только появится jQuery, вызывает method. А внутри method - как раз ваши инлайн-скрипты.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально  создаем переменную, отвечающую за загрузку всех скриптов и размещаем её в первом скрипте

```
var isScriptsLoad = false;
```

Далее в последнем скрипте делаем

```
isScrtiptsLoad = true;
```

Соответственно вставляем где нужно

```
if (isScriptsLoad) { 
    //code 
};
```

И еще, у каждого скрипта должны быть атрибуты `defer defend`. Вроде должно работать.